# GeoWebCaching with GeoServer

Tags: geowebcache

I am using GeoWebCache with GeoServer.
suppose I have seeded a layer to store its tiles. After that around 60% tiles have been created. Now when I requests for the layer from map client, does GeoServer renders the missing tiles by generating these dynamically at it does if tile caching is not used? Or the tiles that have not been created are missed from the layer?

Answer (score 2):

GeoWebCache will receive the request for the tile, if it is in the cache then the cached image is returned. If the tile is not in the cache then GeoWebCache will pass the request onto the WMS it is caching and ask for the tile to be rendered. It will cache the returned tile (assuming no error) and pass the tile back to the requesting client.